# How to find all rows in HBase that have a qualifier by prefix

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have a HBase table in which some information is encoded in the qualifier name.
Something like this:

```
row1: col1_1, col2_1
row2: col1_1, col3_1
row3: col1_2, col3_2
row4: col1_3, col2_2, col3_1
```

I need to find all rows (with all columns) which have some specific qualifier prefix.
In the example above if I look for `col2` I want to find `row1` and `row4` only.

Because I need all the columns, using `ColumnPrefixFilter` is not an option - it will filter non matching columns.

Using `SingleColumnValueFilter` is also problematic - the exact qualifier is unknown. The suffix range although limited, too big to efficiently create a FilterList with all possible values (>50k variants). The query simply timeouts or slower than getting all the rows and filtering them in the application.

I know that a custom filter is an option but I prefer to avoid going this path (using a managed HBase).

Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do with the standard Filters?

Answer (score 0):

HBase does not have standart filter to do what you need. You should implement custom filter.